# Swagger "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" when passing multiple query strings

Tags: .net, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

Swagger is throwing "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" when I try passing two query string values. I am passing 3 different variables one is required and the other two are optional. When trying to pass both optional variables, swaggers throw that error.

It works perfectly on postman or directly from the browser.

```
[HttpGet("{customerId}/campaign/ads")]
public IActionResult GetAds([FromRoute] long customerId, [FromQuery] long? campaignId, [FromQuery] long? adGroupId)
{
    var serviceResponse = _campaignService.GetAds(new GetAdsServiceRequest
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        CampaignId = campaignId,
        AdGroupId = adGroupId
    });

    if (null == serviceResponse || serviceResponse.Count <= 0) return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, serviceResponse.Select(googleAdsRow => new GetAdsHttpResponse
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        CampaignId = googleAdsRow.Campaign.Id,
        AdGroupId = googleAdsRow.AdGroup.Id,
        AdGroupAdAdId = googleAdsRow.AdGroupAd.Ad.Id,
        AdGroupAdAdName = googleAdsRow.AdGroupAd.Ad.Name,
        AdGroupAdAdType = googleAdsRow.AdGroupAd.Ad.Type.ToString()
    }));
}
```

Comment: What's the full error message in the Console tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: seems like CORS issue. just check it.